# Array of generics where generic is parent class

Tags: arrays, swift, oop, generics

I've run into some issue with generics.

I have:

```
class SyncRequest<Type>: ApiRequest<Type> where Type:SyncableModel {} // really empty. Used only for tipisation

class SyncableModel: BaseModel {...} // BaseModel is class also

class SyncServiceImpl: SyncService {
    private var registeredRequests: [SyncRequest<SyncableModel>]
    init() {
        registeredRequests.append(SyncRequest<EventGroup>("{somepath}"))
    }
}
```

but there is a error saying

> "Cannot convert value of type 'SyncRequest<.EventGroup>' to expected
>   argument type 'SyncRequest<.SyncableModel>'"

Is there any way to use child class as generic type?

Comment: What do you mean by “tipisation”? Is `EventGroup` a `SyncableModel`?

Comment: sorry for my bad English. I meant 'Strict typing'

And yes, EventGroup is SyncableModel of course

Comment: Did you try force casting using `as!`?